# SQL select & group by a period of time (timestamp)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, group-by

I want to select the count number and group by a period of time (month, week, day, hour , ...) . So for example I want to select the number of rows and group them by 24h. 

My table is created as follow. The date is timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE MSG
(
   MSG_ID decimal(22) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   MSG_DATE timestamp,
   FILE_REF varchar2(32),
   FILE_NAME varchar2(64),
   MSG_TYPE varchar2(2),
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_FEI_MSG ON MSG(MSG_ID);
```

I tried with this query. With length depending on the time period. But how can I group from now .

```
SELECT substr(MSG_DATE, 1,length),COUNT(*) as total FROM MSG GROUP BY substr(MSG_DATE, 1, length)
```

But how can I group the date from now + time_period ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=group+day

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can group by the TO_CHAR function.

```
select to_char(msg_date, 'X')
      ,count(*)
  from msg
 group 
    by to_char(msg_date, 'X')
```

...where X is the format specification:

- YYYY = 4-digit Year
- MM = Month of year
- DD = Day in month
- WW = Week
- HH24 = Hour of day

You can combine them pretty much however you like